# auth0 router doesn't trigger navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, auth0

I'm using Auth0 with Angular 2. I have the following login code that don't go to the home page after authentication.

To my understanding, the auth0 will not do the redirection. It sends off authenticated event, and it should create an item in localstorage then navigate to the home page.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    lock = new Auth0Lock(this.config.clientID, this.config.domain, {
        auth: {

            responseType: 'token',
        }
    });

    constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig, private router: Router) { 
        // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
        this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            console.log(localStorage);
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try **location.replace('/home')** or **location.replace('http://localhost:4200/home')**